# Are there homogeneous elements with two distinct grades?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

In a graded ring $B=\bigoplus_{d\ge 0} B_d$, the element $0$ is homogeneous with grade $d$ for every $d\ge 0$, in fact since every $B_d$ is an additive subgroup of $B$, then it must contain $0$.

Can  exist an element $b\in B\setminus\{0\}$ such that $b\in B_e\cap B_f$ with $e\neq f$ (a  non-zero element with two distinct grades)? For polynomial rings for example this particular element doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience there are more stupid downvoters than stupid questions...That $B_e\cap B_f=0$ follows from (but is weaker than) the hypothesis that $B$ is the  direct sum of the $B_d$'s.

Comment: About  "weaker" in the preceding post: think of three distinct subvector spaces of dimension one  in a plane: any two of them have zero intersection, and yet the sum of the three is not direct.

Comment: Dear @user121097,  we may disagree on downvotes but I appreciate your candidness: bravo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If an element $b \in B_i \cap B_j$, with $i \neq j$, then $b$ must be zero. Otherwise, the sum $B_i \oplus B_j$ is not direct.

Compare with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups